# How to delete compressed video after upload in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

In my application, when I choose a video and after compressing it system creates two files.When I select another one, again it duplicate it. This is increasing my memory space. Now I wanted to delete the compressed version of file from the system. Can anyone please help me in doing this?

This is my ImagePickerController delegate

```
#pragma mark - UIImagePicker delegate


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        NSURL *videoUrl=(NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        NSString *moviePath = [videoUrl path];

        if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath, nil, nil, nil);

            NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
            isVideoShooted =NO;
            [self navigateToPostAdViewWithURL:videoURL];


        }
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}
```

And the videoURL I get is

file:///Users/webwerks/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/17B6B1EB-8015-4747-81B0-6FB07F713471/data/Containers/Data/Application/18A3DB9A-78CE-4761-A4EB-B35CBFCEF1C5/tmp/trim.A8DC422C-137F-4FF9-878A-E175CE4DDF8F.MOV

And when I upload the compressed video I am deleting the file at this path using following code

```
+ (void)clearTmpDirectory
{
    NSArray* tmpDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() error:NULL];
    for (NSString *file in tmpDirectory) {
        if ([[file pathExtension]isEqualToString:@"MOV"])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), file] error:NULL];

    }
}
```

this code works fine it deletes the video from the path, but still I get one more video file in the photos app. This continuously generate the file every time I upload video. Now I wanted to not to create duplicate file in photos or it should get deleted after upload.

Comment: Can you add your code for choosing and compressing video here? So we can figure out how to help you.

Comment: Actually, I have implemented UIImagePickerControllerDelegate and by default it compressed video file and store it

Comment: No, by default UIImagePickerController does not compress video file https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1658409-editing_information_keys . It is better for you to put your code in your question, so I'm not just assuming things. (you can press edit to add your code in the question).

Comment: I have updated the question with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum`. It will make the video file to be duplicated.

```
if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    isVideoShooted =NO;
    [self navigateToPostAdViewWithURL:videoURL];
}
```